# Constructing two objects that need each other

Tags: c#, architecture

A puzzling architectural question: You have two symmetrical classes `A` and `B`. Each `A`/`B` object may privately produce a value of type `IA`/`IB` using the `A.CreateIA()`/`B.CreateIB()` methods. These values are needed by the opposite classes - `A` needs `IB` and `B` needs `IA`.

The goal is to **write the `PairMaker.MakePair()` function that constructs an interlinks a pair of `A` and `B` objects**. You also have to write appropriate constructors for the `A` and `B` classes. `A` and `B` classes are in different assemblies and don't see each other's internals. The link should be secure - the external code should not be able to access or modify the object fields. You can write additional classes and add any methods to  `A` and `B` as needed - just don't break the security of the link.

```
interface IA { }
interface IB { }

class A {
    IB ib;

    //Some constructor
    //Other members

    IA CreateIA() { }
}

class B {
    IA ia;

    //Some constructor
    //Other members

    IB CreateIB() { }
}

class PairMaker {
    public static Tuple<A, B> MakePair() {
        //What's here?
    }
}
```

This question is similar to [How to construct two objects, with each other as a parameter/member](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371708/how-to-construct-two-objects-with-each-other-as-a-parameter-member), but that question wasn't answered properly.

Comment: [chicken or the egg](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) problem? And btw. having a circular dependency like that (and in general as well) is really a bad idea.

Comment: Well, the constructors are not written, so not all is lost. I actually know a solution, but it's quite ugly-looking.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Does my question really look totally impossible? Should I really add my ugly solution?

Comment: I'm not saying it's impossible. I've just decided not to answer questions like this one, because it helps others write bad code. In such cases I just comment that it's a bad idea.

Comment: I meant multiple close votes and downvote. Actually this is about proper encapsulation and providing different API facades. For example, some class that has "read-only API" and "private API" is being split into two parts (read-only and writeable) that still have to remain connected. But I try not to muddle my abstract programming pattern questions with specifics. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24216616/an-object-that-securely-provides-both-public-api-read-only-and-private-api-re/

Comment: It's kinda tough to argue with Microsoft developer about C# :) But I will. I can think of one case where you need to somehow solve such a problem: if you want to have immutable doubly linked list or doubly linked hierarchy. Maybe there are other cases also.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. I don't like how it looks (I hate those `out` parameters in the constructors).

```
class A {
    IB _ib;

    public A(out Func<IA> getter, out Action<IB> setter) {
        getter = CreateIA;
        setter = SetIB;
    }
    void SetIB(IB ib) {
        _ib = ib;
    }
    IA CreateIA() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}

class B {
    IA _ia;

    public B(out Func<IB> getter, out Action<IA> setter) {
        getter = CreateIB;
        setter = SetIA;
    }
    void SetIA(IA ia) {
        _ia = ia;
    }
    IB CreateIB() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
}
```

.

```
class PairMaker {
    public static Tuple<A, B> MakePair() {
        Func<IA> iaGetter;
        Func<IB> ibGetter;
        Action<IA> iaSetter;
        Action<IB> ibSetter;
        A a = new A(out iaGetter, out ibSetter);
        B b = new B(out ibGetter, out iaSetter);
        iaSetter(iaGetter());
        ibSetter(ibGetter());
        return Tuple.Create(a, b);
    }
}
```